# Rails Not Receiving Post Request on Form Submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been having a problem in production, but not development, where upon submitting a form, the server doesn't receive the post request. Checking the logs, the app receives nothing, as if the form hadn't been submitted.

From a bit of playing around with difference in the form, it appears to be happening when there a lengthy text within the form, eg. a few thousand characters.

Is this a rails production settings issue, or more likely a server issue?  The app is deployed on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk, which I believe is running Passenger Standalone. The form is only receiving text, and no files.

Comment: could you add your route file, the controller action and the form view code so we can take a look?